# MYSQL Query on timestamp ignore seconds

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database that starts an update at say 07:20:00 and will finish at 07:20:04

When I do a query for all entries done at this time I don't really want to do a range but when  I query

```
select * from Locations where timestamp = "2011-03-25 07:20:00"
```

I only get the first 3 entries below.....

What I ideally need is a query that ignores the seconds part so is...

```
select * from Locations where timestamp = "2011-03-25 07:20"
```

But that returns nothing....

```
1159    45.9432 5.0913  2011-03-25 07:20:00 256
1160    52.5254 10.6599 2011-03-25 07:20:00 1515
1161    49.967  7.2264  2011-03-25 07:20:00 1540
1162    54.1803 11.2977 2011-03-25 07:20:01 260
1163    55.1114 12.5347 2011-03-25 07:20:01 261
1164    43.4058 4.86937 2011-03-25 07:20:02 262
1165    42.3209 -0.57372    2011-03-25 07:20:02 263
1166    51.3763 3.23578 2011-03-25 07:20:02 265
1167    50.1532 6.40325 2011-03-25 07:20:02 266
1168    50.7152 4.55064 2011-03-25 07:20:02 267
1169    50.3813 7.92902 2011-03-25 07:20:02 268
1170    52.1096 5.78085 2011-03-25 07:20:02 269
1171    56.0632 -2.6779 2011-03-25 07:20:02 271
1172    48.6551 11.25   2011-03-25 07:20:02 1574
1173    52.4609 5.08926 2011-03-25 07:20:02 272
1174    51.0239 3.02428 2011-03-25 07:20:02 273
1175    48.4228 11.4413 2011-03-25 07:20:02 275
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you want to do a range? What's so evil about

```
select * from Locations 
where timestamp between "2011-03-25 07:20:00" and "2011-03-25 07:20:59"
```

Comment: Is that as efficient as dropping the seconds value?

Comment: @Lee Armstrong: I think it's the most efficient way no matter whether the timestamp has been indexed.

Answer (score 2):

Try first converting your column without second like this:

```
select * from Locations where date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i') = "2011-03-25 07:20"
```